# Unassigned Shards in Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I have an ES cluster which is playing up. At one point I had all primary and replica shards correctly assigned to 4 of my 5 nodes, but in trying to get some onto the 5th node I have once again lost my replica shards. Now my primary shards exist only on 3 nodes.

I am trying to get to the bottom of the issue:

On trying a forced allocation such as:

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "allocate": {
        "index": "group7to11poc",
        "shard": 7,
        "node": "SPOCNODE1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the following response. I am having trouble finding out the exact problem!

```
explanations: [1]
  0:  {
    command: "allocate"
    parameters: {
    index: "group7to11poc"
    shard: 7
    node: "SPOCNODE5"
    allow_primary: true
  }-
decisions: [11]
  0:  {
    decider: "same_shard"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "shard is not allocated to same node or host"
  }-
  1:  {
    decider: "filter"
    decision: "NO"
    explanation: "node does not match index include filters [_id:"4rZYPBOGRMK4y9YG6p7E2w"]"
  }-
  2:  {
    decider: "replica_after_primary_active"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "primary is already active"
  }-
  3:  {
    decider: "throttling"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "below shard recovery limit of [2]"
  }-
  4:  {
    decider: "enable"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "allocation disabling is ignored"
  }-
  5:  {
    decider: "disable"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "allocation disabling is ignored"
  }-
  6:  {
    decider: "awareness"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "no allocation awareness enabled"
  }-
  7:  {
    decider: "shards_limit"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "total shard limit disabled: [-1] <= 0"
  }-
  8:  {
    decider: "node_version"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "target node version [1.3.2] is same or newer than source node version [1.3.2]"
  }-
  9:  {
    decider: "disk_threshold"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "disk usages unavailable"
  }-
  10:  {
    decider: "snapshot_in_progress"
    decision: "YES"
    explanation: "shard not primary or relocation disabled"
  }-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally sorted this. Somehow the Index has gotten a filter applied to it which prevented shard allocation and move.

I removed the filter and the cluster began behaving.

> curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_settings -d '{
>       "index.routing.allocation.include._id" : "" }'

This sets the _id filter to empty. This was previously populated and prevented the filter ever being matched!

Comment: Sir , I am facing same issue/error as above when I am trying to force a shard to be assigned.
My question is how you figured out the filter on the index as I am new to this I am not understanding.
Secondly how the filter stopped the shards to move or get allocated what is the main reason.
Thank you very much.